# Jquery Datetime picker format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I format the date and time both? I can format the time easily and date easily  but not the date and time in combine format. i m using Jquery Datetime picker plugin

This one is work:

```
 $('.date').datetimepicker({
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm', 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' //This does nothing and does not format the data 
    });
```

How do I format the date for this format?

```
"`hh:mm:ss TT, DD, MM dd, yy"`
```

output will be

```
04:10:55 AM, Tuesday, March 27, 2012
```

Comment: I use `dateFormat` and `timeFormat` in my application and it works.

Comment: but i wanna show time format first & then date format how it will set

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var date_obj = new Date();
date_obj_hours = date_obj.getHours();
date_obj_mins = date_obj.getMinutes();

if (date_obj_mins < 10) {
    date_obj_mins = "0" + date_obj_mins;
}

if (date_obj_hours > 11) {
    date_obj_hours = date_obj_hours - 12;
    date_obj_am_pm = " PM";
} else {
    date_obj_am_pm = " AM";
}

date_obj_time = "'" + date_obj_hours + ":" + date_obj_mins + date_obj_am_pm + "'";

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: date_obj_time + ' , ' + $.datepicker.RFC_850
});​
```

P.S. It's not complete, but I hope you can add the seconds part.

Answer (score 0):

You format should be 'H:i:s A, l, F j, Y'

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    format:'H:i:s A, l, F j, Y'
});
```